# Get all rows that overlaps dates

Tags: mysql, date, select, overlap

**Question**

I have a table that holds all the work experience of each employee. I want to get all work experience of employee that overlapped the dates. Below is the sample.

**Scenario**

Employee 1 have a total of two (2) work experience.
Employee 2 have a total of three (3) work experience.

**tbl_work_exp**

| employee_id | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-06-30 |
| 1 | 2021-07-01 | 2021-12-31 |
| 2 | 2021-01-01 | 2022-02-01 |
| 2 | 2021-07-01 | 2021-12-31 |
| 2 | 2022-01-01 | present |
| 3 | --- | --- |
| 4 | --- | --- |
| 5 | --- | --- |
| and so on... |  |  |

The first row of  Employee 2 overlap the dates to its present work experience.

What I need is to get all rows that overlap the dates, like the table below.

**Results**

| employee_id | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2021-01-01 | 2022-02-01 |
| 2 | 2021-07-01 | 2021-12-31 |
| 2 | 2022-01-01 | present |

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is your question again. _What I need is to get all rows that overlap the dates_... overlap what dates?

Comment: The end_date of Employee 2 in third row overlap the date in start_date of fifth row. I need a query to get all the rows of employee_id that occur similar to that.